# Jquery to check the height of all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, each

```
<a href="#" class="button">BUTTON</a>
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child">Content 01</div>
     <div class="child">Content 02</div>
     <div class="child">Content 03</div>
     <div class="child">Content 04</div>
     <div class="child">Content 05</div>
</div>
```

Here's my HTML, I already have it written where you rollover **a.button** and **div.parent** is visible, and on rollout, **div.parent**'s visibility is set to hidden.

I would like to write another script that, on **a.button** hover, jQuery checks each height the of **div.child** in **div.parent**, figures out which is the tallest, and sets THAT as **div.parent**'s height.

I know there will be a each loop, but I don't know how to look and compare values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Try this out](http://jsfiddle.net/566GR/):

```
$('a.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('div.child').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) maxHeight = $(this).height();
    });
    $('div.parent').height(maxHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("a.button").on("hover", function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".child").each(function(){ 
        var height = $(this).height();
        if( height > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = height;
        }
    });
    $(".parent").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: You're going to want to close the quotes on your second-to-last line.